Debugging: Restart application at specific address in Eclipse
I have a C-Application which isn't located at the default start address of the microcontroller.
When starting the debug session in Eclipse, I am using the option "Specify vector table", which works fine.

But whenever I select "Restart" during debugging, the SW runs into nowhere. obviously the "Restart" does not use the runtime option from above.
There is the possibility to specify "Restart configurations", but how to use them to restart at a given address?

Does anybody have an example? Thanks a lot.
I am using Elcipse 4.23
I tried around and searched the web but didn't find anything helpful.

Eclipse 4.23 is two years and 8 releases behind. Can you reproduce your issue with the latest version of the Eclipse IDE, which is currently 2024-03 (4.31)?

As I see you want to debug app which is used with bootloader (I guess that the MCU is STM32).
I would write a very simple bootloader which will stay in the memory (and it will not erased when you flash the app) which will simply set the vector table, and the stack pointer then jump the app reset handler.
I do this this way all the time. I do not think Eclipse will load the stack pointer correctly or set the vector table.

Yes that is correct, MCU is STM32. Actually giving the address of the vtable in the startup option of debugging session works quite fine, that is why I thought, it should be possible with resetting as well.
Having a small bootloader is an option as well.
